# PhpStorm error? Wrong return type: Expected User, returned Eloquest\Model|object at Laravel repository

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpstorm, typeerror

I mean... why? I am defining the query with the model and it is actually returned correctly but PhpStorm is not detecting me correctly.

This is working fine, but it's a pain in the ass to have the warning in IDE.

We want to improve the code quality (with Code Sniffer, PHPStan...) and leave all checks at the warning level, but this is screwing us up.

[image: Better a picture than a thousand words]

Comment: I don't care if we need to use PHPDoc to solve it, but it is better to fix it than keep the warning.

Comment: Try removing the `query()`, it should not be necessary if AdminUser extends Modal

Comment: You can also try and use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper to generate doc blocks for models. This should improve autocomplete as well

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the limitation of IDE automatic code analyse as it is only on the runtime that returned value will have your expected type.

The only way to play around is adding short PHPDoc like following

```
/** @var AdminUser $user **/ 
$user = AdminUser::query()-first();
return $user;
```

It will force the variable type for your IDE and will have no impact on runtime.

Comment: I see....  The only solution with this method is make a return $user->first() because the IDE recommends make direct return if you don't use this var directly

Comment: @DarkPeTruS *"...because the IDE recommends make direct return if you don't use this var directly"* Such a warning should no longer be showing up in a future 2022.1 version (maybe even 2021.3 version, but rather unlikely) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-59730

Comment: But I have the problem that the function first() doesn't exist in AdminUser.... I see that this has no fancy solution

Comment: @LazyOne THANKS. WOW, it's a relief at least

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
/** @noinspection PhpIncompatibleReturnTypeInspection */
```

Before the `function xxx():xxx` line.

And add

```
/**
 * @method static Builder|static newModelQuery()
 * @method static Builder|static newQuery()
 * @method static Builder|static query()
 */
```

Before your BaseModel (if exists).

This is what Laravel-IDE-Helper did.

I asked on YouTrack too.
They said it will never be fixed.

> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-74735